# Как реализовать подобный border?

Tags: html, css, frontend, градиент

Как реализовать подобный `border` двумя градиентами? По идее, они сходятся в правом нижнем и левом верхнем углу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот интересно, откуда скриншот? Разве там нельзя посмотреть код?

Comment: Нет, скрин скинул заказчик

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ

```css
.border-block {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: linear-gradient(-75deg, orange, transparent, orange);
  padding: 4px;
}

.border-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-block">
  <div class="border-wrap"></div>
</div>
```